# Wondering how to make this SQL (SQLite3) query more efficient

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm doing some analysis on WordPress data, and I currently have a local SQLite database with some relevant tables and a python script to do the analysis. I currently run this query, which runs rather slow. I have a feeling that it could be made a lot faster, but I'm unsure how:

```
    SELECT
    wp_postmeta.post_id,
    wp_postmeta2.meta_value address,
    wp_postmeta3.meta_value postal,
    wp_postmeta4.meta_value city,
    wp_postmeta5.meta_value email,
    wp_postmeta6.meta_value firstname,
    wp_postmeta7.meta_value lastname,
    wp_postmeta8.meta_value soort,
    wp_postmeta9.meta_value stamboek_1,
    wp_postmeta10.meta_value stamboek_2,
    wp_postmeta11.meta_value stamboek_3,
    wp_postmeta12.meta_value stamboek_4,
    wp_postmeta13.meta_value phone
    FROM
    wp_postmeta
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as wp_postmeta2 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta2.post_id AND wp_postmeta2.meta_key = '_abo_address'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta3 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta3.post_id AND wp_postmeta3.meta_key = '_abo_postal'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta4 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta4.post_id AND wp_postmeta4.meta_key = '_abo_city'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta5 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta5.post_id AND wp_postmeta5.meta_key = '_abo_email'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta6 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta6.post_id AND wp_postmeta6.meta_key = '_abo_firstname'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta7 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta7.post_id AND wp_postmeta7.meta_key = '_abo_lastname'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta8 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta8.post_id AND wp_postmeta8.meta_key = '_abo_soort'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta9 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta9.post_id AND wp_postmeta9.meta_key = '_abo_stamboek_1'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta10 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta10.post_id AND wp_postmeta10.meta_key = '_abo_stamboek_2'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta11 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta11.post_id AND wp_postmeta11.meta_key = '_abo_stamboek_3'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta12 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta12.post_id AND wp_postmeta12.meta_key = '_abo_stamboek_4'
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS wp_postmeta13 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_postmeta13.post_id AND wp_postmeta13.meta_key = '_abo_phone'
    WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id IN (SELECT post_id from `wp_postmeta` WHERE ( meta_key = '_abo_magazine_tegoed' AND meta_value <> 0 ))
    GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id
```

The idea is to basically transpose the selected post_id, meta_value and meta_key results.

I don't have very advanced SQL skills, and google searches haven't yielded that many useful results. The query works well enough, but I do wonder how it could be made faster. I very much look forward to any suggestions you might have!

Comment: Did you try making tables on the fly, i.e. subqueries which match the meta key? Otherwise an index on metakeys might be a speedup.

Comment: Please provide your schema and several lines of "insert..." to make a [mcve].

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please move that from a comment to the question. With everything you do, please consider whether it makes it easier or more inconvenient to actually help you.

Comment: And do not forget to do the work of writing useable "insert ..." lines, instead of expecting that an answerer does that first, in order to verify an answer against your needs.

Comment: Will look into that and provide a schema with anonymized data, thx!

Comment: It seems that you would benefit from taking the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Using joins to get the other fields and then GROUP BY to remove all the duplicate rows is inefficient.

Better begin with a query that returns only as many rows as needed, and the collect the other values with [correlated subqueries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
SELECT post_id,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_address'   ) AS address,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_postal'    ) AS postal,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_city'      ) AS city,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_email'     ) AS email,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_firstname' ) AS firstname,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_lastname'  ) AS lastname,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_soort'     ) AS soort,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_stamboek_1') AS stamboek_1,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_stamboek_2') AS stamboek_2,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_stamboek_3') AS stamboek_3,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_stamboek_4') AS stamboek_4,
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = m.post_id AND meta_key = '_abo_phone'     ) AS phone
FROM wp_postmeta AS m
WHERE meta_key = '_abo_magazine_tegoed'
  AND meta_value <> 0;
```

Without an index on the `post_id` column, this query will still be slow; but a two-column index on `post_id`,`meta_key` instead would be even better. Additionally, `meta_key` itself should be indexed.